# Enable Cisco ASA as an SSH Tunneling

Tags: ssh, cisco, cisco-asa, ssh-tunnel, putty

I am trying to utilize my Cisco ASA as a SSH Tunnel. I've configured this before when using a Linux server as the SSH target, however I cannot seem to get it to work with the ASA. I have configured and enabled SSH on the Cisco ASA, as well as a username that I can SSH to the console, however the SSH Tunneling feature does not work.

For example, on my PC I use Putty with a Local Tunnel defined to a server behind the ASA. I should be able to (if SSH connected to the ASA) be able to access the server.

See screenshot of putty.
[image]

has anyone come across this before? Again this is to use my Cisco ASA as a SSH tunnel, this
 is not a port forwarding.

-Jim

Comment: SSH tunneling isn't supported; SSL VPN could be an option if you have the correct licensing and you're willing to use SSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco ASAs do not support SSH Tunneling, that's why it doesn't work.